What is the bare minimum schematic for setting up an ATMEGA328P-AU
I don't need the serial programmmer connector anymore. To upload a sketch I'm using the SPI-Communication (MISO/MOSI) instead. So which of those components marked with an questionmark may i remove while keeping the ATMEGA328P-AU alive and working properly - let's say for an blink sketch or for an 7-Segment-LED-Display?

The image above is a common schematic for an arduino uno. I created it and I'm the owner of this schematic - seems it is nec. to mention it.

You can throw everything else out but it depends how you connect it to a supply or what clock you need if you can throw everything out.

playmobox - Hi, Where did the schematic come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/etc. name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. printed book / private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY

The "bare minimum" is dependent on your application, which is information that you haven't provided. Can you provide more details on why you no longer need these parts and what design you're looking for?

playmobox - Hi, Thanks for stating that the schematic is yours. That seemed unlikely since you were asking questions about it, and other site members flagged to us that it therefore likely needed to be referenced.

I've rescinded my downvote. Thank you for clarifying your application. I don't know if others will follow suit because they may have a different concern. Next time, I would encourage you to read application notes provided by Microchip or whatever device you use in the future to really understand the different scenarios that this device can be used for. If you're a professional engineer, this is an important skill to have because you will be making proprietary devices and the only people who can help you with that are the chip suppliers.

Short answer:  As a general rule, you should keep C4 and connect it as close as possible to pins 4/6 in your layout. It's also probably a good idea to keep D1. However, if you don't need accurate analog inputs, you can connect AVCC directly to VCC and drop L1, R1, C3, and C5. It's also possible to eliminate X1/C1/C2 by using the chip's internal oscillator (see below). Finally, if you promise not to tell any electrical engineers, you can run the chip with no external components at all.
Longer answer:
C4 is intended as a power supply bypass or decoupling capacitor. In a PCB layout, it should be placed as close as possible to the pair of VCC pins 4/6 and and should bypass them to your ground plane. Its purpose is to maintain a steady +5V supply free of digital noise. While you could possibly get away with leaving it out, it's risky. You might discover that the microcontroller behaves unpredictably in certain, hard to replicate situations. So, I'd keep it.
The purpose of L1 and C3 is explained in the ATmega328P datasheet in Section 23.6.2 Analog Noise Canceling Techniques. By placing L1 and C3 physically close to the AVCC pin and using a separate analog ground plane, you can minimize the effect of digital noise on the accuracy of analog inputs.  Actually, if analog input accuracy is really important, there should also be an external capacitor on AREF, as described in Section 23.5.1.  Judging from the pin/network names in your schematic, you aren't using the analog inputs as analog inputs; you're just connecting buttons to them. In this case, you don't really need L1 or C3 and can connect the AVCC pin directly to your +5V power supply (as indicated in Section 1.1.7).  AREF can be unconnected.
The purposes of R1 and D1 are explained in the document AVR Microcontroller Hardware Design Considerations in Section 3: Connection of RESET Pin on AVR Devices.  Most AVR devices, including this one, support a parallel programming mode where a high voltage (12V) is applied to the reset pin while VCC is at +5V.  To support this mode, the internal circuitry cannot include an electrostatic discharge (ESD) protection diode from the reset pin to VCC, and so this document recommends adding an external diode to provide such protection if the high-voltage programming mode isn't being used.  R1 is intended as an additional pull-up resistor to supplement the internal pull-up in noisy environments and avoid unintended resets.
The purpose of C5 is to allow the serial programmer to reset the device in a "natural" way.  When the serial programmer activates, it pulls DTR low, and C5 in combination with internal and external pullup resistors pulses the reset low to reset the device
If you are only using the SPI programming interface and are not operating in an unusually noisy environment, then you should be able to drop R1 and C5.  The internal pullup will probably be sufficient to keep the device out of reset.  If you find the device is randomly resetting in your testing, you might want to add R1 back in.
You could also drop D1, but it's a bit risky. With the RESET pin connected only to J1, there's some risk of an ESD through that jumper, if you brush it while trying to connect your programming cable, or whatever.  I guess I'd keep it, though if you don't mind living dangerously, you could drop it.
Assuming you're designing a custom PCB for this, I'd suggest leaving room for R1 and D1, and then you can decide whether or not to populate them later.
Update: The ATmega328P also has a couple of on-board oscillators that can be used in place of the 16MHz crystal, a calibrated 8MHz RC oscillator and a low-power 128kHz oscillator. If you use one of these instead, you don't need X1 or its capacitors C1/C2 and, in fact, you can use pins 7 and 8 as general purpose I/O pins.
There's one tricky issue with this. What makes an ATmega328P an Arduino is mostly the presence of the Arduino bootloader that's preloaded onto the bare ATmega328P chip. This bootloader is what supports programming via the serial interface. Since you're trying to eliminate the serial interface, you may already have configured your IDE to program the chip via an external programmer, effectively bypassing the bootloader. However, the IDE is set up so that loading the bootloader also sets chip "fuses" which determine things like whether an external crystal or internal oscillator are used. So, if you want to continue using the Arduino IDE, you may need to separately use a utility to set the fuses correctly before you can run the chip without the external oscillator or else load a special version of the bootloader. I'm afraid I can't help too much with this. I haven't tried using the Arduino IDE with a chip configured to use its internal oscillator, so I don't know the details. See the YouTube link below for one approach.
The other thing to point out is that the advice above to keep C4 and D1 is based on general good practice: digital chips should have decoupling capacitors and ESD protection, and designers should follow the advice given in datasheets and application notes.
However, if you're a hobbyist interested in pushing the envelope for minimal design, then you're perfectly free to engage in "bad practice"!  Realistically, this chip will usually run just fine without C4, especially if you run it at a reduced clock rate, and realistically, without D1, you probably won't burn out your reset pin unless you really go out of your way to apply a static shock to it.
See this YouTube video Running an Arduino on a breadboard with NO EXTERNAL COMPONENTS for an example of setting up a one-chip Arduino using the internal oscillator and skipping the "niceties" of C4 and D1.

I've upvoted your answer because while OP's application still a tad vague, you've at least addressed why certain components are necessary.

@K. A. Buhr Does that mean, if I'm using a USBtinyISP AVR ISP Programmer, which is using max. 5V to write a sketch to the MCU, I could actually get rid of D1, because I can't run into a situation where 12 Volt is put to VCC, right? Thus when using USBtinyISP AVR ISP Programmer I don't need D1 as well?

It's the other way around. If you don't need +12V programming, then you should include D1 to protect against ESD damage. If you were using +12V programming, then you'd have to leave D1 out (and skip ESD protection or else replace it with something else).  What you're trying to protect against here is accidental application of high voltage to the RESET pin (e.g., through a static charge).

Okay, I think I got it: The diode is protecting the MCU from getting (accidently) +12V. Thank you.
